# Statement.execute() function return Boolean value

Tags: java, sqlite, prepared-statement, exists

I'm trying to do a very simple thing: know if a row exists in my `SQLite DB`.
The `Statement.execute(sqlquery)` function should allow me to do this, as it reads in the description of the function: if the SQL query returns 1 or more rows the `return = true`, if the *SQL query returns 0 rows* its `return = false`.
I don't think is necessary I go deeper into the structure of my DB or my program. I'm doing this quite simple return

```
System.out.println("1---" + stat1.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + TABLA_OFERTAS + " WHERE " + OFERTAS_COL_ID + " = '" + id + "' AND " + OFERTAS_COL_ASIGNADA + " = 'SI')"));
```

Where id is a variable that iterates through every row of the table. I'm just filtering for every row if it has a column with a YES (that should return a true), if that particular column has another thing the SQL query shouldn't match and it should return no value so it should return a `false`.

If I use this same select sentence on an external SQL program this actually returns 0 values, but for some reason, while in my own program this *`System.out` ALWAYS returns `true`*.

I've checked the `"id"` variable and it works fine. I don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. Maybe I've misunderstood the method *Javadoc*. I don't know.
If more info is needed I'm willing to share it.

Comment: I think exists will always return a value — true or false

Comment: I've tryed with a simple Select statement and it doesn't work either, same result, ALWAYS true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query uses `EXISTS` which returns `1` if the conditions are satisfied or `0` if not.
So, you get always 1 row.
Moreover, the method [`execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) always returns `true`, when the sql statement is a `SELECT` query.

What you need is to check the result of the query if it returned `1` or `0`, but you can do it without `EXISTS`, with a `PreparedStatement` and `?` placeholders in the sql statement, which is the safe way to pass parameters to a query:

```
String sql = "SELECT 1 FROM " + TABLA_OFERTAS + " WHERE " + OFERTAS_COL_ID + " = ? AND " + OFERTAS_COL_ASIGNADA + " = 'SI'";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql)); // conn is your connection object
st.setInt(1, id);
ResultSet rs  = st.executeQuery();
System.out.println("1---" + rs.next());
```

`rs.next()` will return `true` if the query returned at least 1 row, or `false` if there are no rows.

I assume that `id` is an integer, but if it is a string change to:

```
st.setString(1, id);
```

Comment: This solution pretty much works like a charm. Thank you very much buddy ^^